# Ruby vs Python: Which is better suited for scripting utilities on Windows? And why?

Tags: python, ruby, scripting

I need to write a bunch of scripts to grab diagnostic data from customer environments where our product is installed.  Troubleshooting data I need comes various sources including Oracle database, PowerShell commands, WMI, Registry, Windows commands such as netstat, our own property files, log files etc.  The results will go into HTML pages, which in turn will be zipped emailed out/FTPed by the script.

Which language is the most suited for this purpose?  Python, Ruby or something else?    I am new to both Python and Ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby's type system is much simpler and cleaner and allows a smaller and simpler language core. And, you write scripts that don't look like OOP in Ruby just as easily because the default "global" namespace is the body of a default "main" object, which just implements all the usual imperative functions like print, gets, eval, etc.
Ruby also allows you to write scripts that don't really look like you're using objects.
Ruby people complain about Python's lack of blocks, the difficulty of doing dynamic code generation, the awkwardness of trying to modify existing classes. They complain about these things

[You Can Also Check This Link](http://mjtsai.com/blog/2002/11/25/perl_vs_python_vs_ruby/)

Comment: @ greppz:- So you should accept this as answer

Answer (score 1):

I started with python and ruby both few months ago. Ruby has loads and loads of issues and I find python really cool. Dint try with scripting. I am working on web apps.
Used python script to to interact with database and inserting raw fields. Works really fine.